# Select data from jquery object

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I've got in my variable (events) two objects:
[image]

I'm trying to get "title" from each object and then send them with ajax two my php file where I will have to separate arrays:

```
array(
    title = "All Day Event";
},
array(
    title = "sdfsdf";
}
```

I've no idea how to do this. I've tried to acces "title" with:

```
events['title]
```

and

```
events.title
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Your code is typo'd, correct them maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get two title like following.

```
var title1=events[0].title
var title2=events[1].title
```

Answer (score 2):

events is an array..

`events[0].title` or `events[0]['title']` will work fine. or use a loop.

```
for (var i = events.length; i--;) alert(events[i].title);
```

Comment: It's exactly what I need! Thanks!